# process.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = size is not working in windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, threadpool

I am following a Node.js course on Udemy by Jonas Schmedtmann. In my system/ laptop I am not able to change the size of thread-pool, while in the instructor's laptop it is working right. The instructor is working on MacBook and I am on Windows 10, please take a look on code give me your suggestions:
Note: My node.js version is 14.5.1

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const start = Date.now();
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 1; // This isn't working


setTimeout(() => console.log("Timer 1 finished"), 0);
setImmediate(() => console.log("Immediate 1 finished"));

fs.readFile("test-file.txt", () => {
  console.log("I/O finished");
  console.log("-------------");
  setTimeout(() => console.log("Timer 2 finished"), 0);
  setTimeout(() => console.log("Timer 3 finished"), 3000);
  setImmediate(() => console.log("Immediate 2 finished"));

  process.nextTick(() => console.log("Process.nextTick"));

  crypto.pbkdf2("password", "salt", 100000, 1024, "sha512", () => {
    console.log(Date.now() - start, "Password Encrypted!");
  });
  crypto.pbkdf2("password", "salt", 100000, 1024, "sha512", () => {
    console.log(Date.now() - start, "Password Encrypted!");
  });
  crypto.pbkdf2("password", "salt", 100000, 1024, "sha512", () => {
    console.log(Date.now() - start, "Password Encrypted!");
  });
  crypto.pbkdf2("password", "salt", 100000, 1024, "sha512", () => {
    console.log(Date.now() - start, "Password Encrypted!");
  });
});

console.log("Hello from the top-level code");
console.log(process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE); // This prints the exact same value which I assigned to it in line# 04 but not making the difference in thread pool size.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more? What would you except to happen when you run the code? https://gist.github.com/rjoydip/36031b3b6d46a9d638e3a97816d2a137

Comment: Why not set it from cli? `SET UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=1 && node index`

Comment: I tried from cli but got error.                                                                                         
 At line:1 char:26
+ SET UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=1 && node event-loop
+                          ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

Comment: Try it with 2 seperate lines if your terminal complains about "&&". First run `set NEWVAR=SOMETHING` then `node ....`

Comment: Tried but not worked...

Comment: "Not worked" is not a error message...

Comment: Actually I have mentioned the error in a comment before.

Comment: Taking the same course and having the same issue... It is even not working with the cli command `set UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=1 && node index`